# Improve performance of stored procedure where only select query is used

Tags: performance, sql-server-2005, select

In our environment one procedure is taking long time to execute. I have checked the procedure, and below is the summary -

1. The procedure contains only select block (around 24). Before each select we are checking if data exists. If yes select the data, else do something else. For example :

   ```
   -- Select block 1 --
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1
             INNER JOIN table2 t2
             ON t1.col1=t2.col1
             WHERE t1.col2='someValue' AND t2.col2='someValue'
             )
   BEGIN
      SELECT t1.col1,t2.col2,t2.col3 FROM table1 t1
      INNER JOIN table2 t2
      ON t1.col1=t2.col1
      WHERE t1.col2='someValue' AND t2.col2='someValue'
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
     SELECT 'DEFAULT1', 'DEFAULT2', 'DEFAULT3'
   END


   -- Select block 2 --
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1
             INNER JOIN table2 t2
             ON t1.col1=t2.col1
             WHERE t1.col5='someValue' AND t2.col5='someValue'
             )
   BEGIN
      SELECT t1.col5,t2.col6,t2.col7 FROM table1 t1
      INNER JOIN table2 t2
      ON t1.col1=t2.col1
      WHERE t1.col5='someValue' AND t2.col5='someValue'
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
     SELECT 'DEFAULT1', 'DEFAULT2', 'DEFAULT3'
   END
   ```

I have come to an conclution that, somehow if we can combine the query that is used within IF EXISTS block into one query, and set some value to some variables so that we can identify which where condition returns true, that can reduce the execution time and improve the performance.

Is my thought correct? Is there any option to do that? Can you suggest any other options?

We are using Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

[Editted : Added] - All select statement doesn't return same column types they are different. And all select statements are required. If there are 24 if block, procedure should return 24 result-set.

[Added]

I would like to ask one more thing, which one of the below runs faster -

1. SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1
   INNER JOIN table2 t2
   ON t1.col1=t2.col1
   WHERE t1.col2='someValue' AND t2.col2='someValue'
2. SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table1 t1
   INNER JOIN table2 t2
   ON t1.col1=t2.col1
   WHERE t1.col2='someValue' AND t2.col2='someValue'
3. SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM table1 t1
   INNER JOIN table2 t2
   ON t1.col1=t2.col1
   WHERE t1.col2='someValue' AND t2.col2='someValue'

Thanks.
Kartic

Comment: You write that there's an "else" in the logic, but I can't see that in the code - can you include it?

Comment: Hi Neville, in actual procedure, that we use we have else block in case data doesn't exists. Also, all the if block are necessary. For example, if our procedure have 24 if-else block, it'll return 24 resultset.

Comment: Can you please include an example of the "else" part? Does it return results from a different query?

Comment: Added ELSE part as suggested.

Comment: What does the query execution plan look like?  Is the performance load focused in any one part of the query or is it spread out evenly?  Are your indexes heavily fragmented?

Comment: All the datasets that this procedure is returning are required. In case the dataset is empty, we are returning default value.

Answer (score 2):

To enhance the performance of select query...create "**index**" on columns which you are using in where clause

like you are using the

```
WHERE t1.col2='someValue' AND t2.col2='someValue' 
WHERE t1.col5='someValue' AND t2.col5='someValue'
```

so create database index on **col2** and **col5**

---

**Temp table**
you can use the temp table to store the result. since you are using same query 24 time so first store the result of below query into the temp table (correct the syntax as require)

```
insert into temp_table (col2, col5)
SELECT col1, col5 FROM table1 t1
          INNER JOIN table2 t2
          ON t1.col1=t2.col1
```

Now use the temp table for checking

```
-- Select block 1 --
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp_table
          WHERE t1.col2='someValue' AND t2.col2='someValue'
          )
BEGIN
   SELECT t1.col1,t2.col2,t2.col3 FROM table1 t1
   INNER JOIN table2 t2
   ON t1.col1=t2.col1
   WHERE t1.col2='someValue' AND t2.col2='someValue'
END

-- Select block 2 --
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp_table1
          WHERE t1.col5='someValue' AND t2.col5='someValue'
          )
BEGIN
   SELECT t1.col5,t2.col6,t2.col7 FROM table1 t1
   INNER JOIN table2 t2
   ON t1.col1=t2.col1
   WHERE t1.col5='someValue' AND t2.col5='someValue'
END
```

Comment: Index is already in place. Both tables contain huge data. So, select query is taking more time. And we are joining same two tables again and again in all select blocks. So only option I can think of is somehow we need to reduce the query used to check the existance of data. Thanks for your reply Rakesh.

Comment: Anyone any suggestion?

Comment: Thank you Rakesh for your input. But don't you think it will increase processing time, as we need to create temp table, insert data into temp table and then select from temp table?

Answer (score 0):

The current structure is not very efficient - you effectively have to execute each "if" statement (which will be expensive), and then repeat the same where clause (the expensive bit) if the "if" returns true. And you do this 24 times. Worst case (all the queries return data), you're doubling the time for the query.

You say you've checked for indexing - given that each query appears to be subtly different, it would be worth double checking this.

The obvious thing is to refactor the application to execute the 24 select statements, and deal with the fact that sometimes, they don't return any data. That's a fairly large refactoring, and I assume you've considered that...

If you can't do that, consider a less ambitious (though nastier) refactoring. Instead of checking whether data exists, and either returning it or an equivalent default result set, write it as a union:

```
   SELECT t1.col1,t2.col2,t2.col3 FROM table1 t1
   INNER JOIN table2 t2
   ON t1.col1=t2.col1
   WHERE t1.col2='someValue' AND t2.col2='someValue'
   UNION  
   SELECT 'DEFAULT1', 'DEFAULT2', 'DEFAULT3'
```

This reduces the number of times you're hitting the where clause, but means your client application must filter out the "default" data.

To answer your final question, I'd run it through the query optimizer and look at the execution plan - but I'd imagine that the first version is fastest - the query can complete as soon as it finds the first record that matches the where criteria. The second version must find all records that match and count them; the final version must find all records and select the first one.

Comment: I am sorry if I'm not clear enough. All select statement doesn't return same column types they are different. And all select statements are required. If there are 24 if block, procedure should return 24 result-set.

Comment: The approach that I have suggested in my question, is it at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could outer-join the results of a query to a row of default values, then fall back to the defaults when the query's results are empty:

```
SELECT
  col1 = COALESCE(query.col1, defaults.col1),
  col2 = COALESCE(query.col2, defaults.col2),
  col3 = COALESCE(query.col3, defaults.col3)
FROM
  (SELECT 'DEFAULT1', 'DEFAULT2', 'DEFAULT3') AS defaults (col1, col2, col3)
LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.col1=t2.col1
    WHERE t1.col2='someValue' AND t2.col2='someValue'
  ) query
  ON 1=1  -- i.e. join all the rows unconditionally
;
```

The method may not suit you in exactly that form you if the subquery may actually return NULLs and those must not be replaced with default values. In that case, have the subqueries return a flag column (just any value). If that column evaluates to NULL in the final query, that can only mean that the subquery hasn't returned rows. You can use that fact in a CASE expression like this:

```
SELECT
  col1 = CASE WHEN query.HasRows IS NULL THEN defaults.col1 ELSE query.col2 END,
  col2 = CASE WHEN query.HasRows IS NULL THEN defaults.col2 ELSE query.col2 END,
  col3 = CASE WHEN query.HasRows IS NULL THEN defaults.col3 ELSE query.col2 END
FROM
  (SELECT 'DEFAULT1', 'DEFAULT2', 'DEFAULT3') AS defaults (col1, col2, col3)
LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT HasRows = 1, t1.col1, t2.col2, t2.col3
    FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.col1=t2.col1
    WHERE t1.col2='someValue' AND t2.col2='someValue'
  ) query
  ON 1=1
;
```